# Inference of Pearson's rho from distribution perturbation

Tags: correlation, covariance, inference

I would like to infer the correlation between random variables $Q$ and $R$, however, I have access only to the distribution of $Q$ and the distribution of $P=Q+R$. We can see how Pearson's $\rho$ appears here:

$\sigma^2_P=\sigma^2_Q+\sigma^2_R+2\sigma_Q \sigma_R \rho$

I'm basically sure with that information alone, it's not possible to estimate $\rho$. But I thought of a cool trick. There's a treatment of $Q$ such that for an initial distribution $Q_0$, the new distribution is scaled by a constant $k_Q$ so that $k_Q Q_0=Q_k$. We can compute $k_Q$ from the ratio of $\mathrm{E}[Q_k]/\mathrm{E}[Q_0]$. The question is whether $R$ is also affected, and of course, we can't measure $R$ directly. We *can* measure the mean effect on $R$.

$\mathrm{E}[R]=\mathrm{E}[Q+R]-\mathrm{E}[Q]$

for treated and untreated. If I make one assumption: that treatment also affects $R$ by a constant $k_R$ so that $k_R R_0=R_k$, we get:

$\sigma^2_P=k_Q^2\sigma^2_Q+k_R\sigma^2_R+2k_Q k_R\sigma_Q \sigma_R \rho$

We have two equations and two sets of measurements... the distribution of $Q_0$ and $Q_0+R_0$, and then $Q_k$ and $Q_k+R_k$, from which we can compute the two variances, and $k_Q$, $k_R$ from differences in the means. So we can then solve for $\sigma_R$ and $\rho$ using the two variance equations. And I've done that. and it gives a reasonable output...

The question: is there any way, given the data I have to test whether my assumption about $R$ scaling is reasonable? Again, this is based on experimental observations. I *cannot* measure the joint distribution.

Comment: Interesting question. I don't see a way to do it from the data you have. Is it possible to do more than one such treatment (at different levels from the first) in each so the assumptions used in the calculation might be checked on the second set?

Comment: Did I understand you right that the main difficulty with your starting problem is that you don't know the _mean_ of $R$? (For, if you knew it, then variance of $R$ and subsequently correlation between $Q$ and $R$ could be quite easily computed.)

Comment: @ttnphns No -- mean of $R$ is readily computed as I showed. But I don't know the *distribution* of $R$ nor it's relationship with $Q$.

Comment: @Glen_b Really good idea.. I do have two treatments, and they give me similar but not quite the same answer. I think $\rho=.22$ or so for the first treatment, and $\rho=.4$ for the second. BUT, the assumption that $Q$'s distribution scales as a constant is provably worse in the second treatment, which I can see by a KS test between $k_Q Q_0$ and $Q_k$, or by plotting their histograms and comparing. If I titrated my treatment to a narrower regime, and got the same results in that regime, is that good support for my assumptions?

Comment: `I'm basically sure with that information alone, it's not possible to estimate r [between Q anr R]`. If you get to know the mean of $R$ somehow without having the distribution itself, you can compute variance of $R$ and the correlation.

Comment: I don't see how... post an answer?

Comment: I realize that I may have misunderstood your original description -- if you have observations on both Q and R (simultaneously) you could just compute sample correlations.

Comment: Think you had it originally Glen. I can measure only $P=Q+R$ and $Q$. Edited to clarify, think the first sentence was confusing..

Comment: To make the confusion more clear, @vector07: What prevents computing $R=P-Q$ if you measured corresponding observations of $Q$ and $P$? Or do by "distributions" you understand something different? What data/information do you have, precisely?

Comment: @ttnphns By distribution I mean (many) observations of the random variables $P$, and, separately, $Q$. They're not paired observations, otherwise, as you point out, this would be trivial!

Comment: So, it appears that you know $\sigma_Q$, $\sigma_P$. What else do you know about your data? Do you know $r_{QP}$, $\bar{R}$, for example?

Comment: If $R$ with the overbar is the expectation, I showed in my post that $\mathrm{E}[R]$ is readily computed. I don't see how the correlation between $Q$ and $P$ is calculable from what I have.

Comment: If you don't know $r_{QP}$ then, I reason, you have no opportunity to compute $r_{QR}$. Sorry.